# "I wake up dreaming" - possible meaning

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I [found](https://psychcentral.com/lib/things-that-go-%E2%80%9Cahhhhh%E2%80%9D-in-the-night/) an example in that particular structure which is:

> During a night-terror episode, the person will partially **wake up screaming, moaning, or gasping** for air.

It is clear that it means the first thing the person will do after waking up is screaming, moaning, or grasping for air.

I want to use the same structure but with the verb (dream):

> I wake up dreaming of ...

As the process of dreaming is known as a fact that it happens during the person's sleep and stops the moment the person wakes up, would *my sentence* mean that the dream stopped immediately after waking up, or would it mean, like in the first example, the moment I wake up, I started dreaming?

I want to convey the first meaning.

Comment: No-one would misunderstand your sentence. You would say _He collapsed while walking to work_ even though the walking ended when the collapse happened.

Comment: It's not true that you necessarily stop dreaming upon waking. Notably, people who have night terrors can continue to dream after waking. They are also sometimes referred to as *waking dreams*. (People can also *day dream*, although that's—mostly—something different. It's more similar to your sense of *wish* or *fantasize*.)

Comment: I don’t think you’re correctly interpreting the first sentence. It doesn’t mean that the person wakes up _and then_ starts screaming and gasping for air – it means that they were already screaming and gasping for air before they woke up, and that this continues after they wake up. Similarly, if you wake up dreaming, I would understand it as the dream continuing even after they wake up. Or alternatively as being deliberately oxymoronic, like the expression _wake up dead_.

Comment: Also note that in the case you quoted, the boy only **partially** wakes up. He’s actually still sleeping when the screaming and gasping occurs – as the article explains, when he actually woke up, he “looked slowly around the room and asked me what happened”.

Comment: @KateBunting _ I wouldn't misunderstand your proposed example either, but its structure is a bit different from mine.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _ Yes, you are right. Thank you for the explanation. Returning to the quotation, I think it should be interpreted as you explained because of "during" at the beginning of it and/or the "well-known" _definition of_ the term night-terrors. So, does that make my sentence interpreted the same way as dreaming is known to have that nature or because of the sentence exact structure so it would mean that with any gerund other than dreaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "I want to convey the first meaning," which is that the dream "stops the moment the person wakes up".

To be explicit about that, you would instead say:

> I woke up ***from*** a dream of . . .

(You can also say use the verb tense *wake*, but I don't find it as common.)

Comment: I intended to write "woke" actually. Thank you for your answer. Whether the person continues their dreams deliberately or not, would my sentence mean that and may mean what I want to convey as well? So it has two meaning and would better be avoided. I know the structure you have suggested, it is clear indeed, but I want to deliver the meaning in a less direct way.

Comment: @TasneemZH I know there is such a thing as *directed dreaming*, where the dreamer, while asleep, is aware of it and able to influence their dreams. But while I mentioned *waking dreams*, I'm not aware of anybody being able to consciously continue dreaming while awake. Dreaming while awake, while possible, is rare—but also outside the person's control. (I believe.)

Comment: I didn't mean _directed dreaming_, I meant to say that I want to phrase the sentence in an indirect way (or less direct way). I don't know the word for saying such a thing but _idiomatic_ would make the most nearer description that I can think of.